# Assign Same Value to All Months of the Year in DAX

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have two date info in my dataset and trying to full fill the upside diagonal of the table.

Sample Dataset,

| Year | MonthNumber | MonthName | Customerid | Deposit_Year | Deposit_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 6 | June | 2956 | 2023 | 6 |
| 2023 | 7 | July | 3257 | 2022 | 12 |
| 2023 | 10 | October | 3624 | 2023 | 10 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | 3258 | 2022 | 12 |
| 2023 | 11 | November | 3629 | 2023 | 11 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | 3261 | 2023 | 1 |
| 2023 | 2 | February | 3258 | 2022 | 12 |
| 2023 | 7 | July | 2551 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 11 | November | 1052 | 2023 | 2 |
| 2023 | 12 | December | 3609 | 2023 | 5 |
| 2023 | 12 | December | 3640 | 2023 | 12 |
| 2023 | 4 | April | 3241 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 6 | June | 3609 | 2023 | 6 |
| 2023 | 4 | April | 3268 | 2023 | 3 |
| 2023 | 12 | December | 3641 | 2023 | 12 |
| 2023 | 9 | September | 2858 | 2023 | 6 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | 1859 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 6 | June | 2689 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 11 | November | 3381 | 2023 | 5 |
| 2023 | 6 | June | 3304 | 2023 | 6 |
| 2023 | 7 | July | 3593 | 2023 | 6 |
| 2023 | 3 | March | 1779 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 9 | September | 3283 | 2023 | 8 |
| 2023 | 9 | September | 1799 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 5 | May | 3302 | 2023 | 5 |
| 2023 | 10 | October | 2836 | 2023 | 1 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | 7316 | 2023 | 1 |
| 2023 | 11 | November | 2961 | 2023 | 11 |
| 2023 | 5 | May | 2867 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 8 | August | 3591 | 2023 | 6 |
| 2023 | 8 | August | 3618 | 2023 | 8 |
| 2023 | 8 | August | 2634 | 2023 | 5 |
| 2023 | 7 | July | 1044 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | 1647 | 2022 | 11 |
| 2023 | 5 | May | 3608 | 2023 | 5 |
| 2023 | 3 | March | 3261 | 2023 | 1 |
| 2023 | 4 | April | 3265 | 2023 | 2 |
| 2023 | 6 | June | 3312 | 2023 | 5 |
| 2023 | 5 | May | 1830 | 2023 | 1 |
| 2023 | 9 | September | 3249 | 2023 | 9 |
| 2023 | 4 | April | 2905 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2023 | 8 | August | 3590 | 2023 | 6 |
| 2023 | 5 | May | 3291 | 2023 | 5 |
| 2023 | 10 | October | 3612 | 2023 | 6 |

**I can calculate the diagonal values by this measure,**

```
Count Distinct Customer First Month of Year =
VAR selected_year= SELECTEDVALUE(table1[Year])
VAR selected_month=SELECTEDVALUE(table1[MonthNumber])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(table1[CustomerID]),
    FILTER(table1, table1[Deposit_Year]=selected_year && table1[Deposit_Month]=selected_month)
)
```

But, I need to assign these diagonal values to **all next months of the year** like below,

(Row= table1(Deposit_Year) and table1(Deposit_Month))

(Column= table1(Year) and table1(Month))

[image]

Thank you,

Veli

Comment: Which table-columns are you using for the `Rows` and for the `Columns` of the Matrix?

Comment: I've updated the question body. Row refers deposit dates and column does year and month

Comment: Rows and Columns from the same table? Can you add a few sample rows in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) to the question please.

Comment: I've added a sample dataset, you can use monthnumber instead of month name on matrix table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a separate "Month" table to be used in the Matrix column.
Create a new Table with the following:

```
Months = 
  SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATESERIES(1, 12),
    "MonthNum", [Value],
    "Month", FORMAT( DATE(2020, [Value], 1), "MMMM"),
    "Month short", FORMAT( DATE(2020, [Value], 1), "MMM")
  )
```

Add `Months'[Month]` as your second column to the Matrix.

Then update your measure to:

```
Count Distinct Customer First Month of Year =
  var y = SELECTEDVALUE(table1[Year])
  var m = SELECTEDVALUE(Months[MonthNum]) // <-- new month table
  var yd = SELECTEDVALUE(table1[Deposit_Year])
  var md = SELECTEDVALUE(table1[Deposit_Month])
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT(table1[CustomerID]),
      table1[Year] = yd && table1[MonthNumber] = md &&
      yd = y && md <= m
    )
```

Comment: This calculates the up of the diagonal, but doesn't assign the same value of the first month of the row.

Comment: Updated answer above, hopefully that is what you are after.